# Only half the screen visible when using PFLoginViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller

I am trying to use the [PFLoginViewController](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFLogInViewController.html) to show a login and sign up screen. I see it ok but can only see half the screen.

Below is my code and also what I see on the simulator. I can't figure out what's wrong. Something with logo.jpg? (logo.jpg dimensions is 916x916)

**Code:**
[image]

**Class if you want to copy and make any mods:**
    import UIKit

```
class LoginSignupViewController: PFLogInViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self
    self.signUpController?.delegate = self

    self.logInView?.logo = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo.jpg"))
    self.signUpController?.signUpView?.logo = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo.jpg"))


}


func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController, didSignUpUser user: PFUser) {
    signUpController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

Finally, **here is the screen**: Seems like the username and password textfields are hidden and only half the login button is displayed.

[image]

Comment: I've been able to resolve this issue myself. The image resolution was too high.

Answer (score 0):

hate to answer my own question but with some tinkering I found the problem, the logo dimensions I was using was too high.